# Invoking flask server from within pytest test

Tags: python, flask

```
import sys
import os
import logging
import requests
import json
import pytest
from multiprocessing import Process
from flask_file import main


@pytest.fixture
def endpoint():
   return "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"

def test_send_request(endpoint: str):
    server = Process(target=main)
    server.start()
    time.sleep(30)

    # check that the service is up and running
    service_up = requests.get(f"{endpoint}")

    server.terminate()
    server.join()
```

I wanted to spin up and spin down a server locally from within a test to test some requests. I know the server itself works because I can run main() from the flask_file itself using `python flask_file` and it will spin up the server...and I can ping it just fine. When I use the above method, the test does seem to do the full 30s sleep without failing, but in those 30s I cannot open the endpoint on my browser and see the expected "hello world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the Flask builtin development server (e.g. `flask run` or `app.run()`, only one connection is possible. So when your test accesses the app, you cannot access it via browser.

Anyway, you should rewrite your test and fixture to use the `test_client`, see the official documentation

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will implement like that! For my own learning, I actually had debug=False and only tried to access the endpoint within the 30 seconds before the requests.get() was called. Shouldn't it have worked in that case?

Comment: Hi, and sorry - I mixed up debug and development mode. I updated my answer!